# Indirect formula = Indirect(H9&"1:1")

Tags: excel-formula

I received an Excel file which has the following formula:
= Indirect(H9&"1:1")
I understand Indirect formula but what is &"1:1"?

Comment: That's probably just a reference to row 1 of another sheet or workbook depending on the contents of H9.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that H9 would contain the at a minimum the sheet name, and potentially the additonal information of file path and workbook name if the work book being referenced is in another directory

Answer (score 0):

When leaving out both `"`'s this will refer to the first row. (It will refer to the cell in the first row in the same column as you typed your formula).

If cell H9 it's value is a letter (for instance: A) and the first row value is 5 the indirect function refers to A5.

If H9 refers to a sheet name you can leave the `"`'s as is and it will refer to the entire first row of the referenced sheet.